# Is a catkin package a node?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am very new to ROS. I did most of the tutorials but have some questions still. This question: Is a catkin package a node?

More in-depth: So I have my catkin workspace and within that workspace I can have multiple packages. Is each package supposed to be a node? or are there multiple nodes within one package? I guess I'm asking what is the standard layout of the catkin workspace? Sorry for such a primitive question and thanks for the help! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239042/is-a-catkin-package-a-node?/) by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A catkin package is not a node.

A package may contain multiple nodes. Usually, developers use packages to group nodes together when those nodes share a significant amount of code or have a similar purpose.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on 2016-07-07**:
Thanks for the help! :)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-07**:
see also: http://answers.ros.org/question/9133/packages-vs-nodes/

**Comment by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on 2016-07-07**:
That helps as well. Thanks!